# How to get div content in an alert box or store as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 contents in a div showing only one content at a time. I append a prev and next button to show the contents of the div one at a time using jquery.
What I will like to do now is to get the content of the div in an alert box when either button is clicked. `alert('content in the div');` or at least store it in a variable to be passed to a controller

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
<div>Blah</div>
<div>Blah blah</div>
<div>Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#tabs div').first().attr('class', 'current');

$('#tabs div').each(function(i) {
i = i + 1;

$(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + i);

if(i !== $('#tabs div').size()) {
    $(this).append('<button class="tabPagination" rel="tab-' + (i + 1) + '">Next</button>');
}
if(i !== 1) {
    $(this).append('<button class="tabPagination" rel="tab-' + (i - 1) + '">Previous</button>');
}                
});            

    $('#tabs div[class!="current"]').hide();

    $('.wkend').on('click', '.tabPagination', function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
       alert('content in the div');
       $('.current').removeAttr('class');
       $('#tabs div[class!="current"]').hide();
       $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
});
```

The html is my view, I will like to get the contents of the div e.g "Blah, Blah blah" when the Next and Previous button is clicked.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `alert($('#something').html());`?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: With your current code: `alert($('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).html());`

Comment: Thank you guys, you have all all being so very helpful. echochamber gave me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @ Koala_dev and SuperScript, is it possible to get just the content e.g Blah.. without the html and the previous, next text. I used $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).text(); but still getting Blah blah previous next. I will like to get just the Blah blah. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NrsuA/3/)

```
var current = 0;
var max = 3;
$('#next').click(function(){
     current++;
     if(current > max)
         current = max;
     else
         window.alert( $('#tabs div:nth-child('+current+')').text() );
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
     current--;
     if(current < 1)
         current = 1;
     else
          window.alert( $('#tabs div:nth-child('+current+')').text() );
});
```

Comment: Hi, I just realized that all the div contents are showing, with my code, they are hidden.

Comment: @Rebe24 Can you explain a in a little more detail exactly what you want to achieve?